# How can I open a new tab or window when a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, href

I have same ancors/hyperlink in my html file. These point to a new website outside my site.
So I want that when the user clicks the link it should open a new tab or window. My website page should not be closed.

How can it be done?

Comment: Don’t do it. You should not impose your opinion about where the new URL should be opened upon your visitors. If I want a URL to open in a new tab I’ll use Ctrl-click, or 3rd mouse button, or whatever. Point is: *I* decide, not *you*.

Comment: But most of the websites does that only. Commercial benefits may be...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<a href="newpage.htm" target="_blank">Click me to open in a new tab/window</a>
```

> Load the linked document into a new
>   blank window. This window is not
>   named.
>
> If there is no existing window or
>   frame with the same name as specified
>   in the target, a new window is opened
>   with a name equal to the value of the
>   target.

Its the setting in a browser that determines whether to open the page in a new tab or in a new window.

Comment: just one underscore ... not 2 :)

Comment: Isn't this behavior deprecated (and discouraged) ?

Answer (score 10):

open in tabs: there is nothing  programatically that you can do to accomplish that, the only thing I'm thinking of is set the browser to open new links in tabs instead of new window...

to open in a new window all you need is to place a target in your anchors

```
<a href="mydomain.com" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

---

and, by the way there are more options to the target

```
target="_blank"
```

opens in a new **Blank** window

```
target="_parent"
```

opens in a **Parent** window (used when dealing with iframes and you want to open the link in other frame)

```
target="_self"
```

opens in it's own/**self** window (used when dealing with iframes and you want to open the link in the current frame)

```
target="_top"
```

opens in the **top** of all frames (it will open on top of all frames in the page, like a no-frame page will be display)

Answer (score 2):

Just add target="_blank" to the <a> tag

```
 <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank"> Click here </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the `target` attribute in your anchors and set it to `_blank`:

```
<a href="http://www.worsethanfailure.com/" target="_blank">Worse Than Failure</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a dupe of [opening links in the same window or in a new (tab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123000/opening-links-in-the-same-window-or-in-a-new-tab) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118567/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-force-opening-a-new-browser-window. Basically - no. And there shouldn't be a way - you shouldn't impose your surfing preferences on unsuspecting others.

Comment: +1 to combat unnecessary and unexplained downvotes on a legitimate perspective, even though I don't personally agree with it.

Comment: Generally I agree.  However, there are cases where popups are necessary.