# How can I open a link in a new tab when the user clicks it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I Would prefer not to use javascript if that's possible but a jquery solution would be fine too. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: target="_blank" wont do the trick?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this entirely depends on the ***user preferences in a browser***.

You can set the `target` attribute for a hyperlink to be `_blank`. Like

```
<a href="someurl" target="_blank">Click me</a>
```

But this also depends on the user settings in a browser, whether to open this in a new window or tab.

Answer (score 1):

`<a href="url" target="_blank"> Click here </a>` - Should open it in a new blank tab.

Only thing here is that target="_blank" has been deprecated by W3C - which generally means it's up to the users preferences in the browser.

[Here](http://www.ajaxblender.com/open-links-new-window-w3c-valid-target-blank.html) is an example of using javascript - if you really need to check against the W3C validator.

Comment: *deprecated not depreciated??

Comment: @controlfreak123 - Ooops - Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

`target="_blank"` is what can be used.  There is no HTML spec item to specify  opening in a tab vs in a new window.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/browsers.html#valid-browsing-context-name-or-keyword

> [for `_blank`] a new browsing context is being requested, and what happens depends on the user agent's configuration and/or abilities

related: [How can I open a new tab or window when a link is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470075/how-can-i-open-a-new-tab-or-window-when-a-link-is-clicked)